# How to print Unicode glyph names for input string?

Tags: command-line, unicode

I'd like to be able to run

```
unicode-names 'abç'
```

and see the corresponding Unicode character names:

```
LATIN SMALL LETTER A
LATIN SMALL LETTER B
LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
```

Printing a string as a series of Unicode glyph names would be useful in several cases:

- Distinguish easily confused characters such as "i" and "í".
- Explain what a literal string actually contains (for example non-printable or unassigned, zero-width characters).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [uniutils](https://billposer.org/Software/unidesc.html) package has the program `uniname`:

```
$ printf %s '…—' |uniname
character  byte       UTF-32   encoded as     glyph   name
    0          0  002026   E2 80 A6       …      HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
    1          3  002014   E2 80 94       —      EM DASH
```

Comment: For minimal output with only the names, use these options: `echo -n …— | uniname -bcegpu`

Comment: @l0b0, UNIX-compliant `echo` implementations would output `-n …—<newline>` for that. Better as `printf %s '…—'` (using single quotes also avoids problems if the bytes of the encoding of those non-ASCII characters happen to be special to the shell)

Answer (score 8):

I don't know a good way to check this from `bash`, but Python has a built-in Unicode database which you can use like in a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, unicodedata
for ch in sys.stdin.read().decode('utf-8'):
  try:
    print unicodedata.name(ch)
  except ValueError:
    print 'codepoint ', ord(ch)
```

You can use this script like this (assuming you called it `unicode-names`):

```
$ echo 'abc©áοπρσ' | unicode-names
LATIN SMALL LETTER A
LATIN SMALL LETTER B
LATIN SMALL LETTER C
COPYRIGHT SIGN
LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
GREEK SMALL LETTER OMICRON
GREEK SMALL LETTER PI
GREEK SMALL LETTER RHO
GREEK SMALL LETTER SIGMA
codepoint 10
```

The database throws a `ValueError` exception for any characters it doesn't know about, so we print their codepoints in decimal (these are unprintable characters, usually).

Caveat: the script assumes your terminal is UTF-8 encoded. If it isn't, you should change the argument of the `decode()` method. Python supports a very wide selection of encodings, yours will definitely be in there.

Comment: Better -- use `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.

Answer (score 2):

I once wrote this `u` script for that:

```
#! /bin/sh -
exec perl -Mcharnames=full -Mopen=locale -lne '
  printf "U+%04X %s\n", ord($_), charnames::viacode(ord($_)) for /./g' -- "$@"
```

Used as:

```
$ u <<< 'ę£½'
U+0119 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH OGONEK
U+00A3 POUND SIGN
U+00BD VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF
```

I also have this `openbox` (my window manager) key binding:

```
  <keybind key="W-J">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>sh -c "notify-send -- \"$(xclip -o | perl -Mcharnames=:full -C -lne 'printf \"U+%04X %s\n\", $_, charnames::viacode($_) for map ord, /\P{ascii}/g')\""</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
```

Which upon pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> sends a notification describing the non-ASCII characters in the primary X11 selection, which you might find useful.