# Print out unicode values of stdin?

Tags: command-line, debugging, unicode, text

I use `od` to print me the octal or hex of a file/stdin/string. This lets me see the ASCII, or UTF-8 encoded, values of my stdin.

But we don't live in ASCIIland anymore. Is there any command that will print out the unicode values/codepoints for the (presume) utf-8 encoded input? I want to know what unicode characters I'm seeing?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34242/how-to-print-unicode-glyph-names-for-input-string       There is also [an (outdated) “recode” program](https://web.archive.org/web/20140620121336/http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/index.html) that performs it as `recode UTF-8..dump`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this if you are on a little endian system:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t ucs-4le | od -tx4
```

or this if you are on a big endian system:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t ucs-4be | od -tx4
```